# Nested mfrow and layout

Tags: r, graphics

I have a plotting function that just uses base graphics to draw a two-pane plot, using `layout`. What I would like is to iterate through thousands of objects, and save the plots to a .pdf file, with three of the two-pane plots per page.

Quick dummy example:

```
examplefunc <- function() {  
  layout(mat = matrix(1:2, nrow = 1), widths = 3:4, heights = 3)
  plot(0)
  plot(0)
}

pdf("exmaple.pdf", height = 10, width = 8)
par(mfrow = c(3,1)) # Also tried using layout here.
examplefunc()
examplefunc()
examplefunc()
graphics.off()
```

The output is a three page .pdf, rather than the desired one page .pdf with three figures. I'd like to keep using layout to get the proportions of the figures correct.

Answer (score 3):

As the help page for `layout` says, it is incompatible with `par(mfrow` and other forms of multiple plotting and using `layout` overrides instead of nests a previous call to `layout`.  So this will be very difficult.

The simplest approach would be to remove the call to `layout` from the function and set up the grid of 6 panels outside the function.  If you wrote the function then that is straight forward, but if using a function from a package then this becomes more difficult.  You can either create your own version of the function without `layout` or some functions have options to only plot one of their plots (and you would just call it multiple times).

Another approach would be to set the pdf file to have 1/3rd the usual height and plot each pair to one page, then use an external tool to combine sets of 3.  Tools like Imagemagick or pdftk may help.

Comment: Thanks. I did read that in the help pages - I was just hoping for a workaround. The plotting function is a generic that I wrote for a package, so I guess I will just have to change my whole approach.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `layout` or `par` you create a new plotting window. Instead, you should only call `layout` once. For example,

```
examplefunc <- function() {  
  plot(0); plot(0)
}
```

Then

```
pdf("/tmp/exmaple.pdf", height = 10, width = 8)
layout(mat = matrix(1:6, ncol = 2, byrow=T), widths = 3:4, heights = c(3, 3, 3))
examplefunc()
examplefunc()
examplefunc()
graphics.off()
```

You can see the layout of the plots via

```
layout(mat = matrix(1:6, ncol = 2, byrow=T), 
                widths = 3:4, heights = c(3, 3, 3))
layout.show(6)
```

Comment: I understand the problem with my approach, but the problem with this approach is that I cannot call the plotting function for an individual object.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: My plotting function is a generic method for `plot`, inside a package I am putting together. I would like to use the generic plot function as written (with the specified layout) to look at individual objects, or to plot all the objects in a single .pdf. I may just have to change the overall approach.